# How do I find task ids for Celery task events based on the arguments passed to them?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm stuck with something I imagine to be simple. **I am trying to determine if I can find all task ids given a known set of arguments. Is this possible with Celery 4.4's API or should I have to code my own interface to the results table in the Django ORM and search myself?**

My use case is one I imagine might be a common one. I have tasks that are scheduled to create Activity and Notification objects for feeds and user profiles. These are set to retry until successful since I need to ensure these objects are created.

However under high load where asynchronous tasks may fall behind, it is possible for a user to do something like post a comment and then delete it before the activity or notification objects get created. A situation like this would require the tasks to be cancelled or be re-queued forever.

The obvious solution to me was to call revoke() on the task ids that had the object id in their arguments from the `post_delete` signal after retrieving a list of task ids from the events api, however I've not been able to clearly find an interface in the api docs that will allow me to do this. I think my answer may be in [celery.events.state.Task](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/4.4.0/reference/celery.events.state.html#celery.events.state.State.event) but if that is an interface for querying Tasks I'm not sure that `args` is searchable. My activity tasks are passed the object id and the `create` boolean from the Django `post_save` signal.

I could grab all tasks of the relevant type like `project.activity.create_comment_activity` but then I'd have to loop every task and unpack the args and check them, which seems horrible for scalability.

I must have missed a trick here, or I just code my own interface for the results backend and search the tasks with the Django ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through the `django_celery_results` module and found that it provides a TaskResult model that provides a native Django ORM interface to the result model. Thus you can search the result with `TaskResult.objects.filter`

As a side note, though the Celery docs cover [integrating the django_celery_results module](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend) they do not mention this `TaskResult` model or it's use. The model is documented [in the module docs themselves](https://django-celery-results.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/django_celery_results.models.html#module-django_celery_results.models).

Example:

```py
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult

# Grab all tasks that have not been successful yet that have the 
# PK for the comment object being deleted in their args
results = TaskResult.objects.filter(
    task_args=(instance.pk, True or False),
    task_name='theden_django.activity.tasks.create_comment_activity',
).exclude(
    status='SUCCESS'
)
```

For a more complete example, this is the final `post_delete` handler for my Comment object, which revokes all tasks with the IDs that have been found, alongside the `post_save` task that creates them:

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
from theden_django.core import celery_app
from theden_django.comments.models import Comment
from theden_django.activity.tasks import create_comment_activity

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Comment)
def schedule_comment_activity_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Creates an activity when comments are created"""
    del sender
    del kwargs
    if created:
        create_comment_activity.delay(instance.pk, created)

@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Comment)
def revoke_comment_activity_task(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Ensures any pending or running tasks are revoked when a comment is deleted"""
    del sender
    del kwargs

    results = TaskResult.objects.filter(
        task_args=(instance.pk, True or False),
        task_name='theden_django.activity.tasks.create_comment_activity',
    ).exclude(
        status='SUCCESS'
    )

    for result in results:
        celery_app.control.revoke(task_id=result.task_id)
```

### Caveat

This implementation does have a huge caveat, as that it will only find tasks that have been tried at least once. I still think there must be a way with the events api. One mitigation for this is to make the task cancellation a delayed task itself, which should ensure that the task is run after all tasks in the queue. For extra caution, I have set this task with a delay of 5 minutes so even if something is horribly slow on a worker the tasks should be recorded in the result backend by the time the revocation task runs.

`handlers.py`:

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models import signals
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
from theden_django.core import celery_app
from theden_django.comments.models import Comment
from theden_django.activity.tasks import create_comment_activity

@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Comment)
def schedule_comment_activity_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Creates an activity when comments are created"""
    del sender
    del kwargs
    if created:
        create_comment_activity.delay(instance.pk, created)


@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Comment)
def revoke_comment_activity_task(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Ensures any pending or running tasks are revoked when a comment is deleted"""
    del sender
    del kwargs

    revoke_pending_activity_tasks.delay(
        (instance.pk, True or False),
        'theden_django.activity.tasks.create_comment_activity',
        countdown=300
    )
```

`tasks.py`:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import logging
from psycopg2 import OperationalError as psycopg2OperationalError
from django.db import Error
from django.db.models import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
from celery import shared_task
from django_celery_results.models import TaskResult
from theden_django.core import celery_app

LOGGER = logging.getLogger()

@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=None)
def create_comment_activity(self, comment_pk, created):
    """
    | Async task that creates an activity for a comment.
    :param `integer` comment_pk:
    :param `boolean` created:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        instance = Comment.objects.get(pk=comment_pk)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist as missing_comment_exception:
        LOGGER.error(
            'Unable to find comment %s. Rescheduling task.',
            comment_pk
        )
        self.retry(exc=missing_comment_exception, countdown=60)
    except (Error, OperationalError, psycopg2OperationalError) as db_conn_exception:
        LOGGER.error(
            'Unable to create comment activity for %s due to database error. Rescheduling task.',
            comment_pk
        )
        self.retry(exc=db_conn_exception, countdown=60)
    else:
        try:
            create_activity(instance, instance.user.pk, created, 'comment')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as missing_member_exception:
            LOGGER.error(
                'Unable to find actor %s for activity. Rescheduling',
                comment_pk
            )
            self.retry(exc=missing_member_exception, countdown=60)
        except (Error, OperationalError, psycopg2OperationalError) as db_conn_exception:
            LOGGER.error(
                'Unable to create comment activity for %s due to database error. Rescheduling task.',
                comment_pk
            )
            self.retry(exc=db_conn_exception, countdown=60)


@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=None)
def revoke_pending_activity_tasks(task_args, task_name):
    """
    | Async task that cancels other tasks
    :param task_args:
    :param task_name:
    :return:
    """

    results = TaskResult.objects.filter(
        task_args=task_args,
        task_name=task_name,
    ).exclude(
        status='SUCCESS'
    )

    for result in results:
        celery_app.control.revoke(task_id=result.task_id)
```